# Jupyter Notebook kernel installation error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I'm using Pycharm and I've installed conda&Anaconda and the jupyter project, however when I try to "register project interpreter as kernel" I get this error, how do I solve it?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\untitled1\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Also I'm trying to put the jupyter notebook (preexisting, it's my homework, which is why it's important to get started on it) in a new python project if that makes any difference.
Thanks!

Comment: did you install `pypiwin32`?

Comment: yeah, but I still have the same error

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment you're using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just met this problem and fixed it.
You can use command "python -m ipykernel install --name XXXX"(xxxx is your new kernel name)  in Pycharm terminal to create a new kernel.
RESTART Pycharm, then switch to your new kernel.